# Almost no FavIcons showing in IE9?

Tags: internet-explorer-9, favicon

Many websites that have Favicons are not showing them in my installation of IE9. The few that do show up include Bing, Windows Live, and Microsoft.com. Even superuser.com shows the default IE logo! What's causing this?

UPDATE: Once I pin a site, the FavIcon shows!

Comment: It's IE, what do you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE has always had problems retrieving and caching favicons.  Microsoft has never put much (any?) effort into correcting the problem, either.  It's been there for as long as I can remember, but at least since IE 6.  A quick Internet search shows many similar complaints and no solutions.  You can search for "IE X favicons" (with 6, 7, 8, and 9 for X) and you'll get the same reports.

I don't believe Moab's assertion that history expiration is to blame, nor that history is a bad place to store favicons.  Chrome and Firefox use History and Cache to store favicons.... although more recent versions of Firefox use Places, and it's is [extremely difficult to remove favicons in Firefox now](http://www.pcmech.com/article/clearing-all-favicons-from-firefox-3-cache-how-to/).

Answer (score 1):

Delete your browsing history, favicons are stored in there, and IE is prone to history corruption or your history is set to too few days to keep and are deleted automatically.

Seems like a bad place to store favicons.

Another reason to use Chrome, Firefox or Opera browser.

[Source of Information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970936/how-to-clear-ies-favicon-cache/3973816#3973816)